.NET 8 - The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32 From Swagger
In .NET 4.7.2, non-nullable fields did not produce an error with the following payload. However, after upgrading to .NET 8, it now throws an error

The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32"

Payload:
{
  "Party": {
    "Id": null
  },
  "Organization": {
    "Id": 3
  }
}

DTO
public class Invoice
{
    public Party Party { get; set; }

    public OrganizationParty Organization { get; set; }
}

public class Party
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationParty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

Here is Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddControllers(configure =>
{
    configure.Filters.Add<ExceptionFilterAttribute>();
    configure.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true;
}).AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

How we can solve this in .NET 8?

The Id property should be made nullable - int? - because you are trying to assign a null value to an Int32, which is a value type, thus does not accept nulls.

Thank you for the suggestion. I had a similar thought and have started implementing it. However, the challenge is that there are many properties like this that need adjustments. I am looking for a simpler and alternative approach.

Well, if using the System.Text.Json serializer, you can set DefaultIgnoreCondition on the JsonSerializerOptions to WhenWritingNull. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.ignorenullvalues.
